# Magento 2 get specific customer group customers list

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-group, magento2.1.5

I have created a custom module and want to get specific customer group users to list in the dropdown.

For this I have gone through the **admin > Stores > Other Settings > Customer Groups** and I have created a customer group named ex. XYZ Customer. Assigned some users to XYZ Customer group.

Now, I want to list all the user who belongs to the XYZ customer group. How I can list all the users in the custom dropdown.

See below is my custom block code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $customerCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
      array $data = []
    ){  $this->customerCollectionFactory  = $customerCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerCollection()
    {   
        $collection = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter("group_id","4");
        $options = [];
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection); die;
        foreach ($collection as $driver) {
        $options[] = ['label' => $driver->getFirstname()." ".$driver->getLastname(), 'value' => $driver->getEntityId()];
        }
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($options); die;
        return $options;

    }   
}
```

Guys help me out this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create Block file in module **Customer.php**

**Path :** `App\Code\{CompanyName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Bookseller\`

```
<?php

namespace {CompanyName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Bookseller;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_customerGroupCollection;
    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
         $this->_customerFactory=$customerFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerGroup($currentGroupId)
    {
           //Get customer group Id , you have already this so directly get name
            $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection- 
              >load($currentGroupId); 
            echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name
            print_r($collection->getData());
    }

    public function getCustomer($customergroupId)
    {
        return $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()- 
             >addFieldToFilter('group_id', $customergroupId);
    }
}
```

Create phtml file in module **Customer.phtml**

**Path :** `App\Code\{CompanyName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Bookseller\`

```
<?php
    $groupId = 1;
    $booksellertCollection = $block->getCustomer($groupId);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($booksellertCollection->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter in customer collection as follows

```
->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id','1');
```

where **1** is customer group id.

Comment: But how I can get customer collection first? Could you please let me know complete process. I have created a block in my custom module to display the dropdown list.

Comment: Please paste your code in question by editing it

Comment: You can see the complete module code in this [Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176593/magento-2-save-custom-order-status-in-custom-table-using-custom-module).

Comment: After this I want to save these customer ID in custom table as well in respect of order id.

Comment: please check the updated question. I have tried with your code `->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id','1');`, but when I use the `customer_group_id` the function will stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_customerCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_context                    = $context;
    $this->_customerCollectionFactory  = $customerCollectionFactory;  
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCustomerCollection() {

    $collection = $this->_customerCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter("group_id","3");
    return $collection->getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer group details and specific group member's customer ids by doing like this

```
 class Trial extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_customerGroup;
protected $_customerFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
     $this->_customerFactory=$customerFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function getCustomerGroup($currentGroupId)
{
       //Get customer group Id , you have already this so directly get name
        $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection- 
          >load($currentGroupId); 
        echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name
        print_r($collection->getData());
}   
public function getCustomer($customergroupId)
{
    return $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()- 
         >addFieldToFilter('group_id', $customergroupId);
}

}
```